# С помощью ajax запроса передать данные PHP скрипту и вывести ответ, который вернет PHP скрипт

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Доброй ночи всем. Есть такая задача - нужно с помощью ajax запроса передать данные PHP скрипту и вывести ответ, который вернет PHP скрипт.

Вот ajax запрос:

```
$('document').ready(function(){ // Поиск по сайту
        $('#searchForm').submit(function(e){
            // прерываем отправку по умолчанию
            e.preventDefault();
            // сереализируем данные формы в строку
            var formData = $("#searchForm").serialize();
            //alert(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                type: "POST",
                // dataType: "json", // Эта строка вызывает error
                data: formData,
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.length > 0) {
                        //alert(msg);
                        //alert("ищюююююююююююююююю!!!");
                        noty({ // Выскакивающее уведомление noty2
                          text: 'Выполняется поиск по каталогу продукции...',
                          type: "information",
                          layout: "topRight",
                          animation: {
                            open: {height: 'toggle'},
                            close: {height: 'toggle'},
                            easing: 'swing',
                            speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
                          },
                          timeout: 2000});
                        $("div.span4").fadeOut("slow");
                        // Как теперь добавить ответ от сервера???
                    }
                    else {
                        $(location).attr('href', updView + "/" + id);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
                    noty({ // Выскакивающее уведомление noty2
                          text: 'Во время поиска по каталогу продукции возникла ошибка. Повторите попытку.',
                          type: "error",
                          layout: "topRight",
                          animation: {
                            open: {height: 'toggle'},
                            close: {height: 'toggle'},
                            easing: 'swing',
                            speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
                          },});
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("div.span9").html("<h1>Результаты поиска</h1>");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
      });
```

Вот PHP скрипт:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
    $title = "Поиск $search";
    require_once('header.inc.php');
    require_once('sidebar.inc.php');
    require_once('mysql.inc.php');
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    echo $search;
    $query = "SELECT title, `text` FROM products WHERE MATCH (title, `text`) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    var_dump($row);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br>";
    if ($row === false) {
        echo "Ничего не найдено.";
    }
    else{
        echo $row[0];
    }
    //mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($conn);
    require_once('footer.inc.php');
```

Как мне вывести ответ от PHP скрипта в событии complete Ajax запроса?

Comment: вот так, 

     complete: function (data) {$("div.span9").html("<h1>Результаты поиска"+data+"</h1>");}

Comment: `dataType: "json"` надо использовать если вы возвращаете массив завернутый с пом-ю [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Сделал, так как Вы написали в первом комментарии - результат [object Object], а как сделать нормальный текст?

Comment: рекомендую отвыкать от alert-а, используйте console.log - тогда сможете корректно видеть объектные переменные

Comment: > а как сделать нормальный текст?

@eprivalov1, все зависит от того, как вы формируете ответ на сервере. Напр.:

    // иногда достаточно
    data[0]
    // или 
    data['key']
    // иногда сначала
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    obj.key

В общем, всё по ситуации

Comment: Спасибо, Всем за ответы. Вообщем добился нужного результата так:

***data.responseText***